# D3.js static force layout not working with path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Im trying change this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139 to use path instead of line, but its not working.
Im try use own tick function like this:

```
function tick() {
            link.attr("d", function(d) {
            var x1 = d.source.x,
                y1 = d.source.y,
                x2 = d.target.x,
                y2 = d.target.y,
                dx = x2 - x1,
                dy = y2 - y1,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),

                // z uzla do ineho uzla
                drx = dr,
                dry = dr,
                xRotation = 0,
                largeArc = 0,
                sweep = 1;

            //do sameho seba
            if ( x1 === x2 && y1 === y2 ) {
                xRotation = -45;
                largeArc = 1;
                drx = 30;
                dry = 30;
                x2 = x2 + 1;
                y2 = y2 + 1;
            }

            return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "A" + drx + "," + dry + " " + xRotation + "," + largeArc + "," + sweep + " " + x2 + "," + y2;
        });     
}
```

I dont know, if i missing something or static force layout just cant use path.
Force layout with path working normaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) (bolding mine):

> simulation.tick()
>
> Increments the current alpha by (alphaTarget - alpha) × alphaDecay;
>   then invokes each registered force, passing the new alpha; then
>   decrements each node’s velocity by velocity × velocityDecay; lastly
>   increments each node’s position by velocity.
>
> **This method does not dispatch events**; events are only dispatched by
>   the internal timer when the simulation is started automatically upon
>   creation or by calling simulation.restart. The natural number of ticks
>   when the simulation is started is ⌈log(alphaMin) / log(1 -
>   alphaDecay)⌉; by default, this is 300.
>
> This method can be used in conjunction with simulation.stop to compute
>   a static force layout. For large graphs, static layouts should be
>   computed in a web worker to avoid freezing the user interface.

Since it doesn't dispatch events your tick function is never called or used.  Instead, just replace the line and set your path up once:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var n = 100,
    nodes = d3.range(n).map(function(i) {
      return {
        index: i
      };
    }),
    links = d3.range(n).map(function(i) {
      return {
        source: i,
        target: (i + 3) % n
      };
    });

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-80))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(20).strength(1).iterations(10))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY())
    .stop();

  var loading = svg.append("text")
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .text("Simulating. One moment please…");

  // Use a timeout to allow the rest of the page to load first.
  d3.timeout(function() {
    loading.remove();

    // See https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#simulation_tick
    for (var i = 0, n = Math.ceil(Math.log(simulation.alphaMin()) / Math.log(1 - simulation.alphaDecay())); i < n; ++i) {
      simulation.tick();
    }

    g.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var x1 = d.source.x,
          y1 = d.source.y,
          x2 = d.target.x,
          y2 = d.target.y,
          dx = x2 - x1,
          dy = y2 - y1,
          dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),

          // z uzla do ineho uzla
          drx = dr,
          dry = dr,
          xRotation = 0,
          largeArc = 0,
          sweep = 1;

        //do sameho seba
        if (x1 === x2 && y1 === y2) {
          xRotation = -45;
          largeArc = 1;
          drx = 30;
          dry = 30;
          x2 = x2 + 1;
          y2 = y2 + 1;
        }

        return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "A" + drx + "," + dry + " " + xRotation + "," + largeArc + "," + sweep + " " + x2 + "," + y2;
      });

    g.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("r", 4.5);


  });
</script>
```

**Response to comments:**

To append a circle and text as a "node", I would create a `g`, position that and then put the circle and text in it:

```
  var g = node
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d){
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("r", 28);

  g.append("text")
    .text("test");
```

Comment: Realy thx, can I ask you one more thing? How add text to every circle? Non static force layout just create var circle.append("g") then append("circle") and then append("text") for add text but that not working here. My try is here https://jsfiddle.net/f7e20crm/. That text ist separate element not part of g element when is circle and text element

Comment: @Martin, see update answer for you question.  And updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f7e20crm/6/).